# Unwanted gap on absolute positioned content on top of relative positioned content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with Chris Coyiers brilliant approach to [full page video](https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/) with content scrolling over the video, but I'm getting an unwanted gap to the right in Windows browsers. The weird thing is that it's not happening in Mac browsers (currently testing in Safari, Firefox and Chrome). In Windows browsers this happens in all the browsers I'm testing with.

The css for the white main content area looks like this:

```
main {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}

main::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -100vh;
}
```

Could it be scrollbar related? Has anyone found a solution to this or can explain to me why this happens in Windows?

Please see this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8y2v79nj/

Chris' article: https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/

Chris' example that I'm using: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BRvdgK

Mac screenshot with no gap:
[image: Mac screenshot]

Windows screenshot with the unwanted gap:
[image: Windows screenshot]

Comment: using a reset.css is a good practice to negate browser specific standards. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thank you for chiming in. The thought struck my mind, and I've tried resetting the css but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from the reserved width for the y-scroller, and you only hide the x-scroller by `overflow-x: hidden;` on `body`.

You can add this to your styles that will help you to get rid of the reserved width of the scroller on `body`.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Full code

```js
var viewportHeader = document.querySelector(".viewport-header");

document.body.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  var opacity = (document.body.offsetHeight - document.body.scrollTop) / document.body.offsetHeight;
  var scale = (document.body.offsetHeight - document.body.scrollTop) / document.body.offsetHeight;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--headerOpacity', opacity);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--headerScale', scale);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --headerOpacity: 1;
  --headerScale: 1;
}

.video-header {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.video-header,
.video-header video,
.video-header .viewport-header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.video-header video {
  background: brown;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.video-header .viewport-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  opacity: var(--headerOpacity);
  transform: scale(var(--headerScale));
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Syncopate", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3vw;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10vw;
  letter-spacing: -1.3vw;
}

main {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}

main::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -100vh;
}

main p {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="video-header">
  <video src="https://css-tricks-post-videos.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Island%20-%204141.mp4" autoplay loop playsinline muted></video>
  <div class="viewport-header">
    <h1>
      Explore
      <span>Montana</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: Hat's off to you sir! It works perfectly. I added scrollbar-width: none; to body for Firefox support as well. Thank you for helping me getting rid of this annoying problem.